# import modules when starting scripts in command-line

Tags: python, windows, python-module

I'm running a python3 script/program that uses my private module MyModule.py. It is placed in my site-packages folder.

When running the script from within python (with `exec(open("path\to\my\script.py").read())` ), everything works fine. Also works `import MyModules`.

However, when I call from within cmd `python "path\to\my\script.py"`, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\jochen.tackenberg>python H:\@work.Jochen\plot_rzsaldo.0.5.3.2_topng.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\@work.Jochen\plot_rzsaldo.0.5.3.2_topng.py", line 14, in <module>
    import rzsaldo_data_current
ImportError: bad magic number in 'rzsaldo_data_current': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

It is exactly the same script as I load with my `exec` command. Even if I add manually my site-packages to my PYTHONPATH using

```
setlocal
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages
```

it does not work.

After several requests, I'm pasting here some snippets of the code to show what I'm trying to do: (this is only the module, not the importing script...)

```
import datetime
import urllib
import urllib.error
# import pdb

def _today():
# returns todays date

    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    return str(todays_date.day) + '.' + str(todays_date.month) + '.' + str(todays_date.year)


class _RegelzonenDataClass():
# This class constructs the data objects, which contains the read-out information from the URL

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.fulltime = []

    def initialize_produkt_container(self, produkt):
        if produkt == 'RZ_SALDO':
            self.rz_saldo = []
        else:
            self.neg_request = []
            self.pos_request = []



class SomeOnlineData(object):
# This class can read in and contain all data necessary 

    def __init__(self, von=None, bis=None, uenbId='Netzregelverbund', produkt='RZ_SALDO'):

        self.url = ''
        self._raw_data = []
        self.data = _RegelzonenDataClass()

    # retrieve data from some webpage and strip data
        self.get_data(von, bis, uenbId, produkt )
        self.read_data()

    def get_data(self, von, bis, uenbId, produkt ):

        if von is None:
            self.von = _today()
        else:
            self.von = von

        if bis is None:
            self.bis = _today()
        else:
            self.bis = bis


        self.url = 'some.url.com/index.php?here' + I_paste + '&some=' + 'argumemts'
        self._raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen( self.url )


    def read_data(self):
    # process the raw html response into the data class


        self.data.initialize_produkt_container(self.produkt)


        for raw_data_line in self._raw_data:

            # check whether the current line is part of the header; if so, skip
            dummy_line_skipper = raw_data_line[0:1]
            if not dummy_line_skipper.isdigit(): continue


            dummy_string = str(raw_data_line).split(';')

            self.data.date.append( datetime.datetime.strptime( dummy_string[0][2:], '%d.%m.%Y' ) )
            self.data.somemore.append( some_data )

            # the data is given in weird german standard - decimal seperator is ','
            self.data.data_column.append( float( dummy_string[2].translate(str.maketrans(',.','.,' ) ).replace(',','' ) ) )
```

What is puzzling me most is the fact that it does not complain at all if I import it from within python.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Cheers
Jochen

UPDATE:
Since none of the suggestions work, for the moment I simply copied all of my module code to the main program. That is nasty, but works...

Comment: Please post the contents of your scripts. It will help to understand what may be the possible cause of the error

Comment: I can't paste the code because it is work related. But it does not include any special or control characters. I mainly find it amazing that it runs if called from within python and does crash if called as argument...

Comment: At least paste an example which reflects what you're trying to do but isn't the code from work - this should include whatever directory structure is involved.

Comment: Did you try to delete the pyc file and "recompile" the corresponding py?

Comment: There is no pyc file. How do I 'compile' such a pyc file? (Usually I'm using Linux and never had to compile such a pyc file...)

Comment: ok, googled this and found them - recompiling does not help...

Comment: I also opened the pyc file in a hex editor and converted the first hex block to decimal numbers. The file starts with 9e 0c 0d 0a ... - 9e becomes 158 - I'm using python 3.3

Comment: Have you checked you really don't have a `rzsaldo_data_current.pyc` file somewhere (site-packages folder)? This error usually appears when there is something wrong with the .pyc files (created with a diferent python version, for example). So check you are not using two different python versions (3 and 2.7 for example)

Comment: Hi Salem, I found the pyc files in the __cache__ folder, deleted it, compiled it manually etc. And I start python simply by typing python in cmd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching a bit on this topic and also based on the comments to thw query, the most likely probability for this error to occur is the mixing up of Python 2.7 and Python 3 versions and the presence of some stale .pyc files within the **site-packages** directory.

When you import a module within another module, it works fine because, the same Python interpreter (v3.3) is used to load the Python modules and hence there is no problem encountered.

since you are facing a problem only when you run it from the command line, it would help to verify which version of python you are using to execute these scripts.

At the command prompt type :

```
python -version
```

this should give you the version of python you are currently using to run your script. Make sure that it is version 3.3. Else, you will need to modify the PATH environment variable to make the path for the 3.3 version of the interpreter ( say **c:\python33** ) come before any other python interpretor version (say **c:\python27** ). You can do this as below:

```
SET PATH=c:\python33;%PATH%
```

assuming Python 3.3 interpreter is present within **c:\python33**

**An edit based on the response from JoChen**

One of the following cases is definitely true:

- plot_rzsaldo.0.5.3.2_topng.py supports only the 2.7 version of Python. This is the file that is causing the **Bad magic Number** error; not your module file.
- There is a stray plot_rzsaldo.0.5.3.2_topng.pyc file somewhere within the directories from where python loads it's files which is generated by Python 2.7.

How did I say that the version of python is 2.7? - Well the answer lies in the magic number which is printed as \x03\xF3\r\n (L.S.Byte -03 and M.S.Byte- F3). This when converted to decimal gives **62211** which is the magic number for **Python 2.7a0  62211** (refer [this](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/import.c?view=markup) link for details). Another interesting [link](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html) also details the structure of **.pyc** files. This link details about the sensitivity of **.pyc** files to the interpreter version.

Given that we do not have access to all the source code and the modules being imported, this is the best that I can answer after my research.

Comment: Hi Prahalad, I only have python 3.3.2 installed. Therefore, both `python --version` and opening python from the command line does give the same result. IT IS compiled from the same version. (As mentioned, I also tried removing the pyc and directly calling `python MyScript.py`; no good as well...

Comment: And you dont have anything like plot_rzsaldo.0.5.3.2_topng.pyc anywhere within your site-packages folder?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the linker pyc, have a look on the directory of your scripts, you may have used two differents versions of python exp 2... 3... etc

just to rm -f the pyc file that causes the problem and you will fix it.